# How to include html files with express and ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

## Code

I want to make my webpage modular so that I don´t need to write my stuff again and again. I thought my solution would be the ejs lib. So I´ve using express and ejs that is configured like this:

```
const app = express();
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/wwwroot/views');
```

My views folder struct looks like that:

```
wwwroot
  static
    css
    js
  views
    login
      index.html
    profile
      dashboard.html
    templates
      inc_header.html
      inc_footer.html
```

My Dashboard has the following content

```
<% include templates/inc_header.html %>

This is my dashboard
```

## Problem

The Header file will not be included. I´ve tried wwwroot/views/templates/header.html and header.html. Nothing works.

## My Whole Serverconfiguration

```
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/wwwroot/views');

app.use(session({
    secret: program.secret || "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/static/')));
```

## Output on the Webserver

> <% include templates/inc_header.html %> This is my dashboard

Looks like the file will not be rendered?

Comment: You don't have a file called `header.html` at all!

Comment: I used inc_header.html. I edited it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from ejs [docs](http://ejs.co):

> Includes are relative to the template with the include call.

Since the file from where you include headers is `dashboard.html` then the path should be:

```
<% include ../templates/inc_header %>
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same. Can it be that the app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile); don´t work? Cause my output is still <% include ../templates/inc_header.html %> This is my dashboard

Comment: Try to remove `.html` extension, i updated my answer

Comment: Try to remove this line `app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);` and set view engine to ejs like this: `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`, and don't forget to to replace all views extensions with `.ejs`

Comment: That´s strange. If I do so he want to download this file. In this file is the source code but it will not be displayed anymore in the browser

Comment: I´ve added my whole express configuration. Maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: You should remove this line `app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);`

Comment: I´ve tried it but it still just download the file and don´t display them on the browser

Comment: The views folder does not contain static files, that's why you have to move it outside `wwwroot/` directory, then set the views folder like this `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` and view engine: `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`

Comment: Still won´t work. It´s the same. If I try to res.sendFile to the dashboard.ejs it will be just downloaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163792/discussion-between-younel-and-lukas-gund).

Answer (score 1):

<%*-* include templates/inc_header.html %>

### include template tags of ejs has a hyphen attached to the opening tag

add the hyphen to the include tag and it will work.

you can also send data to the file being included

```
     <%- include("../partials/head.ejs", {variant:e.name}); %>
```

but *NB:* if a variable is to be used in it, it has to be passed to it from anywhere it is being included.

to solve this issue you can set a default value to it if not sent
Add this to the file being included

```
    <em>Variant: <%= typeof variant != 'undefined' ? variant : 'default' %></em>
```

for more check out this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

for using html files in express using ejs, use this in the index.js(entry point for tour application)

```js
const app = express();
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```